# why variables can be variable in List Comprehensions?

Tags: erlang

as we know that variables can't be variable in erlang. but consider this code,why each value of [1,2,3,4] is sequentially pattern matched to N,and don't throw exception??

```
1> [2*N || N <- [1,2,3,4]].
[2,4,6,8]
```

Comment: How else would you express a list comprehension?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Saying that a variable can't be variable isn't quite true. It's more that a variable can only be assigned once. So the following psuedo-code is illegal:

```
N = 4;
foo(N);
N = N + 1;
foo(N);
```

However, the following is legal:

```
fact(0) -> 1,
fact(N) -> N * fact(N-1).
```

When we call fact(4) N will take the value 4 then 3 then 2 then 1 for each different function call. The code you are showing above is similar. For each item in the list N takes on a different value. But you never assigned the value of N more than once.

Comment: yeah,never assigned the value of N more than once, but why each value of [1,2,3,4] is sequentially pattern matched to N?? `[2*N || N <- [1,2,3,4]].`

Comment: @huwang Try not to think of it as an *assignment*. It's a way to express the algorithm. You can call the above `fact(N)` with different values for `N` as often as you want, right? It's basically the same in a list comprehension.

Comment: oh,it might be a Syntax sugar!

Comment: @huwang In one sense a list comprehension **is** syntactic sugar, for a recursive function. A better way of reading it is as tiny DSL expressing rules on how to build a list.